# Comparing values in columns A & B and returning a specific word in column C

Tags: lookup

Model/Example

```
         ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC
(Header) CLOSED     id      STATUS
          100       85       OPEN
          200       95       OPEN
          300       100     CLOSED
          400       300     CLOSED
```

ColumnA will likely have 1000 rows and less
ColumnB will likely have 500000 rows and less

If a cell value in ColumnB is in found in ColumnA, then  adjacent cell in ColumnC should display CLOSED, otherwise it should display OPEN.

Comment: Is this in a database, or something else?